# Template specialization works fine with gcc but not with visual studio 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, gcc, template-specialization

I have this template specialization in my code that works perfectly fine when I compile it with gcc but doesn't when I compile it using Visual Studio 10's compiler :

**Field.cpp**

```
template<>
void Field<std::string>::setValueString(const std::string &val)
{
  operator=(val);
}

template<>
void Field<bool>::setValueString(const std::string &val)
{
  bool v = static_cast<bool>(atoi(val.c_str()));
  operator=(v);
}

template<>
void Field<int32_t>::setValueString(const std::string &val)
{
  int intv = atoi(val.c_str());
  operator=(intv);
}

template<>
void Field<int16_t>::setValueString(const std::string &val)
{
  int intv = atoi(val.c_str());
  operator=(intv);
}
```

**Field.hpp**

```
template<typename FieldType>
class Field : public FieldBase
{
public:
  Field(const std::string &fieldName)
    : FieldBase(fieldName), _overriddenInsertValue(this) {}
  ~Field() {}

  (...)

  /**
   * @brief Template specialized for every available field type in Model.cpp
   */
  void setValueString(const std::string &)
  {
    ALT_ERROR("Field::setValueString called with wrong argument type.");
  }
};
```

On windows for some reason I always end up in the error case but I don't understand why, since it works fine when I run it on linux/mac os using gcc.

Comment: What exactly does the error say ?

Comment: Its sad, but nowadays (C++11 widely implemented/used, and C++14 ready to go) MSVC is not one of the best compilers to work with C++. If someone disagrees, please read the VS2013 roadmap: Sounds like a bad joke.

Comment: The error is that I end up in the default `SetValueString` function ("called with wrong argument type") instead of the specialized case I should end up with. It finally worked properly when I moved the specializations to the header file, how strange is that?

Comment: @Damien T: The only way to move these specialization to header file is to make all functions *inline*. Meanwhile, it looks like in your original code you didn't want to make them inline. If you don't want to make them inline, then they *have* to be defined in the `.cpp` file or you'll end with linker errors. Again, as it is stated in the answers, you probably simply forgot to declare your specializations in the original version of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *define* your template specializations in `.cpp` file, you still have to *declare* all of your template specializations in the header file

```
template<> void Field<std::string>::setValueString(const std::string &val);
template<> void Field<bool>::setValueString(const std::string &val);
template<> void Field<int32_t>::setValueString(const std::string &val);
template<> void Field<int16_t>::setValueString(const std::string &val);
```

The above declarations have to be present in the header file. I don't see them in your code.

You cannot just specialize the templates in some `.cpp` file and then expect the compiler to somehow magically know about it in all other translation units. This is what the declarations in the header file are for.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm just amazed that it worked fine on mac os/red hat when I used gcc as the compiler.

Comment: @Damien T: Must be some peculiarity of gcc's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to properly specialize the implementation of the functions from Field.cpp you need to declare the functions first in Field.hpp.

To specialize for a type you need something like this:

```
template<>
class Field <int32_t> : public FieldBase
{
public:
  ... rest of the functions
  void setValueString(const std::string &);
};
```

Hope this helps,
Raxvan.

Comment: The OP wants to specialize individual member functions. Your example shows how to specialize the entire class, which is a completely different thing.

Comment: Yes, but you still need to declare the functions, by specializing the whole type you do that and i think it's a better practice since you don't have mysterious declarations (like template<> void Field<int32_t>::setValueString(const std::string &val);) for a specific type that ends up doing something unexpected. It might be confusing if working in teams.

Comment: Specializing the entire class and specializing individual functions are completely different things that serve different purposes. The latter can probably be replaced with the former, but it can lead to massive code duplication (i.e. the entire class will have to be redefined for each specialization). I don't see the point. And I don't understand what "confusing" and "teams" have to do with it.